# How to utilize unit-testing without classes and def functions in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am currently in my intro to Python class this semester. We constantly make small-scale programs. Such as the program I just made that takes a function, a domain and finds the root (We assume the user will input a domain that has exactly one root) using bisection.

We made test cases that we just simply commented on our program:

- ## TEST CASES:

  ## f(x) = 4x^3-5x^2+2x+6  D: {-50, 70} Root: -3/4

## f(x) = x^3+10x^2+ 10x + 10 D: {-50, 50} Root: -9.014

## f(x) = 7x^3 + 0x^2 + 3x -2 D: {-100, 40} Root: 0.45

## f(x) = 5x^3 + 2x^2 -3x + 4 D: {-100, 100} Root: -1.317

That got me to look more in depth with testing and I ran across the unittest import. I searched videos about it but every video I ran across assumes that you have classes and are using the def function.

This program doesn't does not use that. Only reads in a function and domain and we use that to find the root.

So, is there anyway we can use unittest to pass values that could be inputted by the user? Or can is it only possible when we call classes and defs? If it's not, what else can you suggest I use?

P.S this is simply for my understanding... unittest is not required for any assignment.

Comment: Do you want to validate user input, before doing any type of calculation?

Comment: We assume that the user is friendly and will enter a valid input. I did add code that checks for that but it's nothing I aim on testing. Only if the coefficients of the cubic polynomial and the domain give me the correct root.

Comment: Well, about testing, u can do it using `unittest` library or `assert` keyword

Comment: Why would you not use functions and classes?

Comment: This is partly because my group is new to programming and classes would be a whole other level of explaining to do.. so I am assuming that we have to have def and classes to use unittest?